# list of lists - get list with distinctive adresses only

Tags: python, list, pointers

I have list of lists like that:

```
a = [[sth1], [sth2], ...]
```

where many values in the array are the same (`a[i] is a[j]`) for some `i, j`.
(that was achieved with a[i] = a[j]).

Now i would like to get a new list, where there are just distinctive lists inside.

To clarify:

```
a = [[1],[0], [3]]
a[0] = a[1]
```

I would like `[a[0],a[2]]`, so without `a[1]` since `a[1] is a[0]`

Comment: It won't work since lists are not hashable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy lists like that, duplicates will have the same memory address, so you can utilize that.

```py
import ctypes

a = [[1],[0],[3]]
a[1] = a[0]

print(a)  # this will print 1,1,3

a = [ctypes.cast(address, ctypes.py_object).value for address in set([id(sub_list) for sub_list in a])]

print(a)  # this will print 1,3
```

by using `set` function you get rid of duplicate pointers and then you simply convert it back from addresses into lists. This of course would not work if you did not use `a[i] = a[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but it might take a while for very long lists

```py
a = [[1], [2], [2], [3]]
set_a = set(x for l in a for x in l)
new_a = [[i] for i in set_a]
print(new_a)

>>> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: Yeah that is to slow and does not care about different addresses.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates then? Because in ````a = [[1], [0], [3]]```` there are no duplicates